# Control flow in Django template language

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have the following code, written inside a Django template.

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <div style="float: right;">
    {% for rel in RELATIONS %}
        {% if rel.group_id == g.id %}
            <a href="/group/{{ g.id }}/unsubscribe/" class="form-button">Unsubscribe</a>
        {% endif %}
    {% else %}
        <a href="/group/{{ g.id }}/subscribe/" class="form-button">Enrol</a>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

The purpose of the code is to check if there is a match and then print out the unsubscribe tag. If there is not match print out the subscribe tag.

The reason I am having trouble doing this is because you in Django templates, I read that you can't have variables (i.e. a True or False).

UPDATE: (The question)

I want to only print out the Unsubscribe/subscribe button once. Print out the unsubscribe button only if there is a match inside the for loop. Otherwise print out the subscribe button if there is no match (i.e. no match at all for rel.group_id == g.id )

UPDATE 2:

While doing some research earlier I found this: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/3481
This might add some context to my problem.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase the question.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like your if/else/endif are mixed up. Try

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <div style="float: right;">
    {% for rel in RELATIONS %}
        {% if rel.group_id == g.id %}
            <a href="/group/{{ g.id }}/unsubscribe/" class="form-button">Unsubscribe</a>
        {% else %}
            <a href="/group/{{ g.id }}/subscribe/" class="form-button">Enrol</a>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

---

**UPDATE**

You want to check if `g` is in `relations` and make your decission based upon that.
The way I usually solve this is to create a function in my view that does this check and passes that allong to the view. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106849/is-if-element-in-alist-possible-with-django-templates).

Comment: There are multiple relations that I need to check. If there is a match in rel. group_id == g.id I want to print out the unsubscribe one (i.e. the user is in the group). If there is no match in the rel. group_id == g.id, they are not in the group and so print out the enrol into a group tag.

Comment: So you need `else if` statements as well (more than the two cases already in there)? From what I can see the above code does exactly what you describe.

Comment: I only want it to print once though, not multiple times. So as it checks each rel and it doesn't have a match it will print out the enrol every single time. I only want it to do it once.

Comment: Also, I know they are mixed up, I was trying to do a for-else loop, however its not in Django

Comment: This will print one or the other for every rel in RELATIONSHIPS. What exactly is `g`?

Comment: I only want it to print out once, not for each RELATION. I was looping through it to find a match. If there is a RELATION, print out the subscribe button. Otherwise don't print it out. So by the end of the whole loop, it should only print out one button (subscribe or unsubscribe). Not multiple buttons.

Comment: 'g' is the users group id. If the users group id is a match they are in the group. Hence they would need an unsubscribe button. Otherwise if they are not enrolled in the group, they would need the subscribe button.

Comment: Oh, I see. You want to check if the group `g` is in the set of `relations` and make your decission based upon that. The way I usually solve this is to create a function in my view that does this check and passes that allong to the view. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106849/is-if-element-in-alist-possible-with-django-templates